# Jmeter sending 2 requests for each GET request

Tags: jmeter

I am doing load testing for one website. Website actual address is configured with SSL so it is something like https://www.example.com

When I start load testing for pages with GET requests , Jmeter is sending 2 requests for each page, one with **Http** & second is **Https**. So I get in listener like this :

```
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
```

How can I tell to jmeter that site has only version with **https** so do not send request with **http**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add 'https' in the protocol section.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Its like if you hit your URL i.e. "https://www.example.com" by replacing "`https`" with "`http`" it will `redirect` to you "https" by default
Similar way if you not mentioned any protocol in your "`HTTP REQUEST`" it will take default value i.e. "`http`", and in listener you see both URL.
For making that it will hit only the "`https`" URL you need to put "`https`" in Protocol text box.

Refer the below snapshot:-

[image]

Comment: No Problem
But please can you correct my name in your comment.
Thanks

Comment: Apologize for mistake in name, Deleted comment.